# Hyperledger Indy World demo project Building error

Tags: python, hyperledger, hyperledger-indy

when trying to build the network from the [indy-ssivc-tutorial](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain-Identity/indy-ssivc-tutorial) is throwing error

I have installed docker and docker-composer and it's running on ubuntu 16 lts. when I type the command ./manage build it fails to create the network with following error code:

> E: Version '1.2.237' for 'indy-plenum' was not found
>   E: Version '1.2.297' for 'indy-node' was not found
>   ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y     indy-plenum=${indy_plenum_ver}     indy-anoncreds=${indy_anoncreds_ver}     indy-node=${indy_node_ver}     python3-indy-crypto=${python3_indy_crypto_ver}     libindy-crypto=${indy_crypto_ver}     vim' returned a non-zero code: 100

```
$ cd von-network
$ ./manage build
```

```
nikhilck@ults-Latitude-3400:~/Desktop/indy-ssivc-tutorial/von-network$ ./manage build
WARNING: The IP variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The IPS variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Building client
Step 1/40 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 5f2bf26e3524
Step 2/40 : ARG uid=1000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c0bf9302443f
Step 3/40 : ARG indy_stream=master
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fa6bad648fde
Step 4/40 : ARG indy_plenum_ver=1.2.237
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f68d93971f51
Step 5/40 : ARG indy_anoncreds_ver=1.0.32
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b5e3aa40d9bd
Step 6/40 : ARG indy_node_ver=1.2.297
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d611097d0a30
Step 7/40 : ARG python3_indy_crypto_ver=0.2.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9b7573bb9234
Step 8/40 : ARG indy_crypto_ver=0.2.0
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 493d2a486240
Step 9/40 : ENV LC_ALL="C.UTF-8"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> edd25e32b63f
Step 10/40 : ENV LANG="C.UTF-8"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e6ac37430cfc
Step 11/40 : ENV SHELL="/bin/bash"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 13df6dfd3564
Step 12/40 : ENV RUST_LOG=error
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b8f74fbdef9f
Step 13/40 : RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y     git     wget     python3.5     python3-pip     python-setuptools     python3-nacl     apt-transport-https     ca-certificates     build-essential     pkg-config     cmake     libssl-dev     libsqlite3-dev     libsodium-dev     curl
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 200ad692285e
Step 14/40 : RUN pip3 install -U     pip==9.0.1     setuptools
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f52769980d10
Step 15/40 : RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 68DB5E88
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2c437a98df6d
Step 16/40 : RUN echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial $indy_stream" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d67cf3fc5a5f
Step 17/40 : RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash -u $uid indy
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 35a175a87295
Step 18/40 : RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y     indy-plenum=${indy_plenum_ver}     indy-anoncreds=${indy_anoncreds_ver}     indy-node=${indy_node_ver}     python3-indy-crypto=${python3_indy_crypto_ver}     libindy-crypto=${indy_crypto_ver}     vim
 ---> Running in eba1bdf7b107
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [109 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [109 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]
Get:5 https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial InRelease [28.4 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [1396 kB]
Get:7 https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial/master amd64 Packages [322 kB]
Fetched 2071 kB in 4s (447 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Version '1.2.237' for 'indy-plenum' was not found
E: Version '1.2.297' for 'indy-node' was not found
ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y     indy-plenum=${indy_plenum_ver}     indy-anoncreds=${indy_anoncreds_ver}     indy-node=${indy_node_ver}     python3-indy-crypto=${python3_indy_crypto_ver}     libindy-crypto=${indy_crypto_ver}     vim' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

The Indy world demo is archived hence these issues are there. I tried to fix by updating the versions, but then there was dependency errors. You can try by finding the correct indy-plenum and indy-node versions and replacing them in the von-network/Dockerfile